# Checkbox values not being updated in tkinter

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, checkbox

I'm pretty new to python and trying to create a GUI using tkinter for a program (manipulating csv files). I will have file names in a list, I need checkboxes corresponding to these files which I have accomplished using the below code. The only hurdle now is getting the state of the checkbox into another dict/list which I can use further down the code. Any help would be appreciated.  Partial code below. Also getting an error while trying to extract values of the checkboxes in click6()

```
from tkinter import *

window0 = Tk()

chkstate2 = []
fileNAMES3 = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
intvar_dict = {}
intvar_dict = dict.fromkeys(intvar_dict, 0)

def click2():
    window7 = Tk()
    window7.title("Choose files to plot")

    for in1c, in2c in enumerate(fileNAMES3[:], start = 0):
        intvar_dict[in2c] = IntVar()
        chk = Checkbutton(window7, text=fileNAMES3[in1c], var=intvar_dict[in2c], onvalue=1)
        chk.grid(column=0, row=in1c)

    def click6():       
        for a,b in enumerate(intvar_dict[:], start=0):
            if intvar_dict[b].get() > 0:
                chkstate2.append(intvar_dict[b])
        window7.destroy()

    btn7 = Button(window7, text="OK",command=click6)
    btn7.grid(column=0, row=in1c+1,padx=10, pady=10)
    btn7.config(height = 2, width = 20 )

btn2 = Button(window0, text="Choose", command=click2)
btn2.grid(column=2, row=7,padx=20, pady=5)

window0.mainloop()
```

Comment: you don't have to use `start=0` in `enumarate()` - as default it uses  `start=0`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `[:]` is not something you can meaningfully apply to a dictionary.  (It's not accomplishing anything in the other two places where you used it, either.)  A more fundamental problem is that you appear to be calling `Tk()` more than once in your program, which causes all sorts of problems.  Use `Toplevel()` to create additional windows.

Comment: did you use `Tk()` two times ? You should use `Tk()` only to create main window. For other windows you should use `Toplevel()` . And this can make your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much guys!! Replacing Tk() with Toplevel() did the trick! I spent hours for this should have just come here lol, thanks again!